# FancyBox plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, lightbox

I have a problem with my fancy box. when I click on a link, the fancy box gets the content but doesn't show the lightbox and jumps to a page that I supposed to get its returned content via Ajax.

**HTML :**

```
<a class="butt red medium fancybox" href="http://localhost/food/index.php/food/ajaxExtras?foodId=412">سفارش </a>
```

**JS :**

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox();
```

**My Result :**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

from your shapshots,
i can say that you havnt added the  plugin files for fancy box .

here are the links for jquery fancy box plugins.just add them in between your header tags

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js

js/fancybox-1.3.4/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js

kindly see the demo in http://fancybox.net/ for further info

Comment: I'm not that amateur.

Comment: this is an optional script and doesn't affect the proccess

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening an external page you may need to set the `type` of `content`, either using an API option  like

```
$("a.fancybox").fancybox({
    type: "ajax" // or "iframe"
});
```

or using the HTML5 `data-fancybox-type` attribute in your link like

```
<a data-fancybox-type="ajax" class="butt red medium fancybox" href="http://localhost/food/index.php/food/ajaxExtras?foodId=412">سفارش </a>
```

Please notice that most ajax calls require to be tested in a server environment and may not work in localhost.

Also make sure you are wrapping your fancybox script code inside the `.ready()` method.